# Idris not recognizing equivalant types

Tags: binary, type-mismatch, idris, dependent-type, binomial-heap

I'm trying to implement Binomial Heaps in Idris, so I defined a type

`data Bin = MSEnd | B0 Bin | B1 Bin`

where `MSEnd` stands for "Most Significant End" (e.g. `B0 (B1 (B1 MSEnd))` represents `6`).

I also defined a function to add them together. I have tested this, and it works as expected
(as does the helper function `succ`, which increments a binary number).

```
plus : Bin -> Bin -> Bin
plus MSEnd b = b
plus b MSEnd = b
plus (B0 a) (B0 b) = B0 $ plus a b
plus (B0 a) (B1 b) = B1 $ plus a b
plus (B1 a) (B0 b) = B1 $ plus a b
plus (B1 a) (B1 b) = B0 . succ $ plus a b
```

However, in a different function whose type signature is dependent on this `plus` function, I get the compiler error

```
Type mismatch between
                b1
        and
                plus b1 MSEnd
```

Based on the definition of `plus`, it seems like the Idris compiler should easily be able to determine that these are equal. What is wrong here?

Comment: It would help if you could provide `succ` and `in a different function` or provide a gist. Otherwise one can only guess what is happening.

Comment: Is plus known to be total? Try putting a "total" annotation on its type signature.